# How do I use Strapi and register a user that authenticated using facebook?

Tags: flutter, strapi

I'm trying to implement Facebook login using Flutter with Strapi backend, but I couldn't figure out how I would be able to integrate them properly. After successful login in Flutter, I get user details and access token, how do I then use this to properly create a user on Strapi with facebook provider?